# How can I move turtles created in a different function in Python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm very new to working with `python` and coding in general but I've been playing around with `turtle` for the past couple of days. I'm trying to create several functions where other functions move a turtle created within a different function. For instance:

```
import turtle as t

def setUp():
    t.setup(900,600)
    t.colormode(255)
    win = t.Screen()

def turtles():
    t1 = t.Turtle()
    t1.shapesize(1.5,1.5,0)
    t1.color('red')
    t1.pensize(3)
    t1.shape('turtle')

def moveTurtle():
    t1.forward(50)

setUp()
turtles()
moveTurtle()
```

In my example here when `python` gets down to `moveTurtles()`, `t1` isn't recognized due to it having been created in a previous function. If anyone could give me some insight into how I could go about doing this I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

**option 1:**

return variable from first method and send it to second method:

```
import turtle as t

def setUp():
    t.setup(900,600)
    t.colormode(255)
    win = t.Screen()

def turtles():
    t1 = t.Turtle()
    t1.shapesize(1.5,1.5,0)
    t1.color('red')
    t1.pensize(3)
    t1.shape('turtle')
    return t1

def moveTurtle(t1):
    t1.forward(50)

setUp()
moveTurtle(turtles())
```

**option 2:**

Using global variable which is not recommended but usable:

```
import turtle as t

t1 = None

def setUp():
    t.setup(900,600)
    t.colormode(255)
    win = t.Screen()

def turtles():
    global t1
    t1 = t.Turtle()
    t1.shapesize(1.5,1.5,0)
    t1.color('red')
    t1.pensize(3)
    t1.shape('turtle')

def moveTurtle():
    t1.forward(50)

setUp()
turtles()
moveTurtle()
```

Answer (score 0):

**option 3:**

Turtles, and the screen object, are global entities by design of the turtle package.  (A turtle local to a function doesn't get reclaimed when the function returns.)  Simply make them global, and access them globally or pass them to where they're needed:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def setUp(w):
    w.setup(900, 600)
    w.colormode(255)

def turtles(t):
    t.shapesize(1.5, 1.5, 0)
    t.color('red')
    t.pensize(3)
    t.shape('turtle')

def moveTurtle(t):
    t.forward(50)

win = Screen()
t1 = Turtle()

setUp(win)
turtles(t1)
moveTurtle(t1)
```